# Turning string into executable python code, and holding that variable name

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables, exec

I'm looping over the following:

*a* might equal some task, like wash_dishes or play_piano

```
exec("%a = Production(Precondition({%s}),Action({%s},{%s}))" %(a, precondition, stop, start))

list_a.append(a)
```

expect: list_a = [wash_dishes, play_piano] (where wash_dishes is a production created above, not "wash_dishes")

`a` holds a string (parsed from a JSON), and I want to add the value of `a` (as a variable) to a list.

Thanks in advance! Hope that made sense!

Comment: Any time you find yourself wanting to access variables dynamically, you're probably doing something wrong. Use a dictionary instead.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you're trying to do. What does `a` hold, and which variable are you trying to assign? Show some more code, and show what you expect the result to be.

Comment: So your trying to access the _actual_ textual value of the variable which an object corresponds to? _Bad idea_. Use a `dict` instead like @Barmar suggested.

Comment: Ya, dictionary was my first go to, but I'm building a parser for an existing production system... I need to take strings from a file to build productions to send in batches to the production system. I can't figure out a clean way to do that in a dictionary

Comment: `symbolTable[a] = "banana"`

Comment: Note: updated the question with some more details

Comment: Why can't you just do `list_a.append(Production(Precondition(precondition), Action(stop, start))`?

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary. In the `exec()` code, put quotes around the place where the variable is substituted, so it will use its value as a string.

```
symbolTable = {}
exec("symbolTable['%s'] = Production(Precondition({%s}),Action({%s},{%s}))" %(a, precondition, stop, start))

list_a.append(symbolTable[a])
```

Comment: It's just the variable that holds the dictionary.